# is there a way to access a validators blockstore

Tags: validator

I am looking for a way to possibly access a validators blockstore or view a public validators metrics externally as i dont seem to see any websocket subscription to be able to view this data.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** - No, shreds in the blockstore and detailed performance metrics are generally not available to the public from validators. Specific information can be queried through RPC calls.

---

When requesting information from a Validator, public users are generally accessing an RPC Node (non-voting validator) that synchronizes with one or more (voting) Validators, or a Validator that opens access to it's RPC service. Many Validators choose not to open these publicly and in these cases you will not be able to request information from them via RPC calls.

To get information beyond what is available via RPC calls, such as accessing shreds in the blockstore or requesting validator metrics, commands would need to be sent using the Solana CLI such as `solana logs` or `solana transaction-history`. These commands can be tested against a local node that you deploy, as long as you have available hardware sufficient to catch up to current network state. If you want these results from a specific validator, they would need to allow remote code execution which is a significant security concern, or they would need to make this information available for you via additional API calls.

**Can I request shreds or detailed metrics from a Validator? No.**
It is very unlikely that you will be able to query the blockstore of a validator directly without a private agreement or accessing it through an additional service they offer.

**Can you request Block, Transaction, or performance information from a Validator? Yes.**
If you are looking for blocks, transactions, accounts, and basic performance metrics these are all available through Solana RPC requests on any Validator that chooses to allow them.

**Relevant Terminology:**

- **Slot** - The period of time for which each leader ingests transactions and produces a block.
- **Block** - A contiguous set of entries on the ledger covered by a vote. A leader produces at most one block per slot.
- **Shred** - A fraction of a block; the smallest unit sent between validators.

**Further Reading:**

- Solana CLI - https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage
- Anatomy of a Validator - https://docs.solana.com/validator/anatomy
- Gossip Service - https://docs.solana.com/validator/gossip
- Blockstore - https://docs.solana.com/validator/blockstore
- Solana Terminology - https://docs.solana.com/terminology